# How to name a file from a folder in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file named **InputFile.txt** in a resources folder. 
My project structure is like this:

- VirtualMemory

  - src

    - resources

      - InputFile.txt
    - VirtualMemory

      - VirtualMemory.java

And I am trying to access the InputFile.txt in VirtualMemory.java class by like this:

```
String filename = ("./src/resources/InputFile.txt");
File file = new File(filename);
```

But the file is not being found. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Since the file resides within the program context, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to get a reference to it, for example `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/InputFile.txt")` will return an `InputStream` to the contents of the file

Comment: Can you please provide code for this?

Comment: I did, look at the comments

Comment: I need to locate file, but the code will return InputStream.

Comment: You can't, essentially, it's not `File` in sense of a file on the file system, it's a named resource, which is stored as series of bytes inside the jar file

Comment: When I used 
InputStream filename = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/InputFile.txt");
 File file = new File(filename.toString());   
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
 br = new BufferedReader(fr);
This error will show java.io.BufferedInputStream@677327b6 (No such file or directory)File: "java.io.BufferedInputStream@677327b6" not Found.

Comment: then how can I implement like this:

InputStream filename = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/InputFile.txt");

File file = new File(filename.toString());  

 FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

br = new BufferedReader(fr);

Comment: Wrap the `InputStream` into a `InputStreamReader` into a `BufferedReader`, for example; `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/InputFile.txt")))`

Comment: Hi! Everytime, while I need to work with files and I dont know how to correctly write path to a file, I'm using following thing- one you have instanced "File", you can call (and print) actual path- look in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html
There is getAbsolutePath() :o)